# How can I know if Snowflake will create a new SQS Queue?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

According to the Snowflake documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html#step-4-configure-event-notifications):

> Following AWS guidelines, Snowflake designates no more than one SQS
> queue per S3 bucket. This SQS queue may be shared among multiple
> buckets in the same AWS account. The SQS queue coordinates
> notifications for all pipes connecting the external stages for the S3
> bucket to the target tables. When a data file is uploaded into the
> bucket, all pipes that match the stage directory path perform a
> one-time load of the file into their corresponding target tables.

I am configuring Snowpipe and relying on the ARN of the SQS Queue provided by snowflake (which can be queried via `DESCRIBE PIPE <pipe name>`). But I am confused regarding the statement:

> This SQS queue may be shared among multiple
> buckets in the same AWS account

Does Snowflake use a single SQS Queue for all buckets? How do I know whether to use the same SQS Queue or if Snowflake will create a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the SQS queues used by the pipes:

```
select pipe_name, notification_channel_name from information_schema.pipes;
```

I created 3 pipes for testing which uses 2 buckets in same account, and I see that all of them uses the same SQS queue.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/pipes.html